# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.addAuthHeader

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have class Dropbox.java which contains upload file function :

```
public class Dropbox {
        static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "<My-Access-Token>";

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
        static final  DbxClientV2 clientV2 = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

    static public void UploadFile(String path, InputStream in) throws UploadException, DbxException, IOException
    {
        clientV2.files.uploadBuilder(path).run(in);
    }
}
```

and call method as below

```
InputStream in = getInputStream();
String path="/newFileName.jpg";
Dropbox.CreateFile(path, in);
```

I have added these three jars for dropbox:
dropbox-core-sdk-1.8.2.jar
dropbox-core-sdk-2.0-beta-4.jar
jackson-core-2.6.1.jar

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.addAuthHeader(Ljava/util/ArrayList;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/ArrayList; from class com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxRawClientV2.uploadStyle(DbxRawClientV2.java:176)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.upload(DbxFiles.java:8290)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles.access$5900(DbxFiles.java:25)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles$UploadBuilder.start(DbxFiles.java:8338)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxFiles$UploadBuilder.start(DbxFiles.java:8304)
at com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxUploadStyleBuilder.run(DbxUploadStyleBuilder.java:29)
    at classes.Dropbox.CreateFile(Dropbox.java:30)
    at servlets.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:50)

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the old jar :
dropbox-core-sdk-1.8.2.jar

and used DbxClientV1 instead of DbxClient in the class